# Direct way to get the Hyodo-Kato Galois action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A group object $G$ in smooth proper rigid spaces has formal semistable model (possibly after a finite extension).

Hyodo-Kato give the cohomology of $G$ a $(\phi, N)$-model structure which by Fontaine-Colmez is the same as a Galois action.

Is there a more direct way to get this action starting from $G$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why not take the $p$-adic etale cohomology of $G$?

Comment: How to construct the Galois action on that?

Comment: Base change to the completed algebraic closure of $K$ first.